# How to make a readable FAT16/FAT32 partition on usb stick for Windows access?

Tags: windows, partitioning, usb, format

I want to create a windows accessible partition(FAT16/FAT32). But even the created partition can read under linux.  It can not see on Windows. Just display a driver symbol like E:.

I'm using parted to create the partition.
And then use mkdosfs -a -F32 -v /dev/sdc2

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 2022MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4096B   22.0MB  22.0MB  primary  ext3
 2      22.0MB  56.6MB  34.6MB  primary  fat32        lba
```

Comment: According the maintainer of dosfstools. Daniel Baumann <daniel at debian.org> told me.
That's Windows' feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A current up to date Windows 10 system can see several partitions in a USB drive.
- But previous versions of Windows (XP, Vista, 7, 8) can see only the first partition in a USB drive. This is also the case with early versions of Windows 10 (that have not been upgraded with the relevant program packages).

If you have a Windows system, that can only see the first partition in a USB drive, you should *make the partition, that you want Windows to see, 'partition #1' (number 1) in the partition table.* It need not be located at the beginning of the drive space (at the drive's 'head end').

When you create a partition table in a USB drive, you can start by creating the partition, that you want Windows too see. Then it will be 'partition #1'. You can use `gparted` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [linuxquestions thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-format-to-fat32-and-how-to-mount-my-fat32-partition-386916/), Windows needs the FAT32 ID type to be `0xc` instead of the `mkdosfs` default of `0xe`.

In my anecdotal experience, GParted will automatically make FAT filesystems that Windows can read, so if that is an option, it may be something to consider.